# What causes the tasks to not evenly partition in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, load-balancing, partitioning, data-partitioning

In my experience, sometimes when I apply `transformation()` to large data, it seems that the tasks are not evenly partitioned and are skewed to one side so that only a few tasks are working. As a result, it was confirmed that the efficiency of the work was poor.

When the tasks are not evenly partitioned:
[image]

I want to know in more detail the cause of when the tasks are biased towards one another.

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you provide some code as to how you're creating the dataframe and what is your datasource? You can always try `.repartition([number_of_partitions],col([partitioning_column]))` to repartition your dataframe before calling the transformation

Comment: Regardless of my code, if the task is not evenly distributed, what causes it?